# can azure web role instantiate an activeX component?

Tags: asp.net, com, azure, activex

I have an asp.net website that I'm looking to migrate over to Azure.  I have been doing some analysis of the website and code to understand issues with the migration.  I am confident that 95% of the code will be fine as most of it is pretty standard web forms and dot net programming.

However, I have just run across an ActiveX component that is installed into the \windows directory on the webserver.

I am wondering if this will be an issue for the migration?  There could easily be a number of follow-on questions as well depending on the answer.  How do Azure web roles handle instantiation of activeX server components?  Can I include the DSINTX.OCX file into the solution or do I wrap it in a dotnet assembly?

```
private DSINTXLib.Dsintx m_dsintx;
...
m_dsintx = new DSINTXLib.DsintxClass();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation of the ActiveX component should not be difficult.  You can use a startup task running elevated to install it, assuming that there's an unattended installation mode for it.  I blogged about this process for a Windows Service a while back.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/golive/archive/2011/02/11/installing-a-windows-service-in-a-worker-role.aspx

If you don't have an installation file, then create a script that installs and registers the control and then use RDP to your role instance to debug.  The blog post goes over some of these techniques as well.  (Use notepad to create the command file, not VS.)  You can add the OCX to your project, but be sure to set the Copy Local property to True so it becomes part of the package that is sent to Azure.